# combineLatest not working

Tags: angular, rxjs6, combinelatest

I created a new angular6 project with angularfire2 and rxjs 6. I am debugging the loading bar to be shown while loading observables.

my ts code:

```
import { combineLatest, Observable } from 'rxjs';

groups: Observable<Array<any>>;
singles: Observable<Array<any>>;
combined: Observable<Object>;

public loadall()
{
    this.groups= this.db.collection('groups').valueChanges();
    this.singles= this.db.collection('singles').valueChanges();
    this.combined = combineLatest(this.groups, this.singles);
    //took this from https://auth0.com/blog/whats-new-in-rxjs-6/
}
```

my html template:

```
<ng-template #loading>
  <div class="loader"></div>
</ng-template>

<div *ngIf="combined | async; else loading"> //this div
  <div *ngFor="let group of groups | async">
    {{ group.name }}
    <div *ngFor="let single of singles | async">
      {{ single.name }}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Currently without the //this div bracket, the output will be displayed. However, with the //this div bracket, output does not get displayed.

With the previous version of rxjs, I used:

```
this.combined = Observable.combineLatest(query$);
```

And this works. So I figure my implementation of the combineLatest operator is wrong. Appreciate help to further debug this.

Comment: Any errors in the console? Have you tried to declare `combined` as `Observable<any>`? The code looks like it should work!

Comment: I tried declaring as Observable<any>, but the information still does not show up. There's no error in the console. I tried to console.log the subscribe value. It indeed shows there some output but unfortunately the html is not showing it with the *ngIf=combined |async" div

Comment: What was `query$` in your old code `Observable.combineLatest(query$);` - I don't see that in new code

Comment: Yea, query$ is just like this.groups = this.db.....valueChanges(). I put it there differentiate the old usage and the new usage syntax.

Comment: Your code looks alright.   As per documentation `Be aware that combineLatest will not emit an initial value until each observable emits at least one value. ` -   Can you confirm that both `this.groups` and `this.singles` are emitting values?

Comment: Yep, I have tested that both valueChanges() has subscribed output in console. I just cannot figure out why passing the two observables to the combineLatest function does not work.

Comment: forkJoin does not work too. However I have a new observation: If i use combineLatest, the loading bar actually disappears but the output does not gets displayed. Using forkJoin, the loading bar does not disappears which means that this.combined does not gets emitted values

Comment: I tested `combineLatest` - it seems to work just fine. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dj8vy4

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176492/discussion-between-user776914-and-wand-maker).